# PowerShell FTP download files and subfolders

Tags: powershell, download, ftp, subdirectory

I like to write a PowerShell script to download **all files** and **subfolders** from my FTP server. I found a script to download all files from one specific folder, but I also like to download the subfolders and their files.

```powershell
#FTP Server Information - SET VARIABLES
$ftp = "ftp://ftp.abc.ch/" 
$user = 'abc' 
$pass = 'abc'
$folder = '/'
$target = "C:\LocalData\Powershell"

#SET CREDENTIALS
$credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)

function Get-FtpDir ($url,$credentials) {
    $request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $request.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
    if ($credentials) { $request.Credentials = $credentials }
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $response.GetResponseStream() 
    $reader.ReadToEnd()
    $reader.Close()
    $response.Close()
}

#SET FOLDER PATH
$folderPath= $ftp + "/" + $folder + "/"

$Allfiles=Get-FTPDir -url $folderPath -credentials $credentials
$files = ($Allfiles -split "`r`n")

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass) 
$counter = 0
foreach ($file in ($files | where {$_ -like "*.*"})){
    $source=$folderPath + $file  
    $destination = Join-Path $target $file 
    $webclient.DownloadFile($source, $destination)

    #PRINT FILE NAME AND COUNTER
    $counter++
    $counter
    $source
}
```

Thanks for your help (:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The .NET framework or PowerShell do not have any explicit support for recursive file operations (including downloads). You have to implement the recursion yourself:

- List the remote directory
- Iterate the entries, downloading files and recursing into subdirectories (listing them again, etc.)

Tricky part is to identify files from subdirectories. There's no way to do that in a portable way with the .NET framework (`FtpWebRequest` or `WebClient`). The .NET framework unfortunately does not support the `MLSD` command, which is the only portable way to retrieve directory listing with file attributes in FTP protocol. See also [Checking if object on FTP server is file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36895021/850848).

Your options are:

- Do an operation on a file name that is certain to fail for file and succeeds for directories (or vice versa). I.e. you can try to download the "name". If that succeeds, it's a file, if that fails, it a directory.
- You may be lucky and in your specific case, you can tell a file from a directory by a file name (i.e. all your files have an extension, while subdirectories do not)
- You use a long directory listing (`LIST` command = `ListDirectoryDetails` method) and try to parse a server-specific listing. Many FTP servers use *nix-style listing, where you identify a directory by the `d` at the very beginning of the entry. But many servers use a different format. The following example uses this approach (assuming the *nix format)

```
function DownloadFtpDirectory($url, $credentials, $localPath)
{
    $listRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $listRequest.Method =
        [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::ListDirectoryDetails
    $listRequest.Credentials = $credentials
    
    $lines = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    $listResponse = $listRequest.GetResponse()
    $listStream = $listResponse.GetResponseStream()
    $listReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($listStream)
    while (!$listReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        $line = $listReader.ReadLine()
        $lines.Add($line) | Out-Null
    }
    $listReader.Dispose()
    $listStream.Dispose()
    $listResponse.Dispose()

    foreach ($line in $lines)
    {
        $tokens = $line.Split(" ", 9, [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
        $name = $tokens[8]
        $permissions = $tokens[0]

        $localFilePath = Join-Path $localPath $name
        $fileUrl = ($url + $name)

        if ($permissions[0] -eq 'd')
        {
            if (!(Test-Path $localFilePath -PathType container))
            {
                Write-Host "Creating directory $localFilePath"
                New-Item $localFilePath -Type directory | Out-Null
            }

            DownloadFtpDirectory ($fileUrl + "/") $credentials $localFilePath
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "Downloading $fileUrl to $localFilePath"

            $downloadRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($fileUrl)
            $downloadRequest.Method =
                [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::DownloadFile
            $downloadRequest.Credentials = $credentials

            $downloadResponse = $downloadRequest.GetResponse()
            $sourceStream = $downloadResponse.GetResponseStream()
            $targetStream = [System.IO.File]::Create($localFilePath)
            $buffer = New-Object byte[] 10240
            while (($read = $sourceStream.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)) -gt 0)
            {
                $targetStream.Write($buffer, 0, $read);
            }
            $targetStream.Dispose()
            $sourceStream.Dispose()
            $downloadResponse.Dispose()
        }
    }
}
```

Use the function like:

```
$credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "mypassword") 
$url = "ftp://ftp.example.com/directory/to/download/"
DownloadFtpDirectory $url $credentials "C:\target\directory"
```

The code is translated from my C# example in [C# Download all files and subdirectories through FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37038676/850848).

*Though [Microsoft does not recommend `FtpWebRequest` for a new development](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0003.md).*

---

If you want to avoid troubles with parsing the server-specific directory listing formats, use a 3rd party library that supports the `MLSD` command and/or parsing various `LIST` listing formats; and recursive downloads.

For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) you can download whole directory with a single call to [`Session.GetFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles):

```
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
    HostName = "ftp.example.com"
    UserName = "user"
    Password = "mypassword"
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Download files
    $session.GetFiles("/directory/to/download/*", "C:\target\directory\*").Check()
}
finally
{
    # Disconnect, clean up
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

Internally, WinSCP uses the `MLSD` command, if supported by the server. If not, it uses the `LIST` command and supports dozens of different listing formats.

The [`Session.GetFiles` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles) is recursive by default.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Thank you verry much. Works perfect with winscp!

Answer (score 4):

For retrieving files /folder from FTP via powerShell I wrote some functions, you can get even hidden stuff from FTP.

Example for getting all files and subfolders (even hidden ones) in a specific folder:

```
Get-FtpChildItem -ftpFolderPath "ftp://myHost.com/root/leaf/" -userName "User" -password "pw" -Directory -File
```

You can just copy the functions from the following module without needing any 3rd library installed:
https://github.com/AstralisSomnium/PowerShell-No-Library-Just-Functions/blob/master/FTPModule.ps1