# Selecting files with current date in file name in WinSCP and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, winscp

I am new to WinSCP and PowerShell.
I am trying to look for files in a directory that has the pattern `"ABC"+somenumbers+YYYYMMDD+somenumbers.zip`

```
$dt = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd') 
$transferOptions.FileMask = ("ABC*>=" "+$dt+".zip")
```

I am not able to get any files downloaded to local directory.
Is my file mask correct?

Thanks
MR

Comment: Would you confirm that that is actually what you have for the filemask, as it looks to me as if there is a typo. Also, the `>` syntax [appears to be](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask) for the file modified time, not something you can use within the filename portion.

Comment: The file name has today's date with format YYYYMMDD. I didn't know >= is only for modified dates

Comment: I suspect you want `$transferOptions.FileMask = "ABC*$dt.zip"`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/43746835/850848#43776537

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I think I missed the second "*", but I put it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the date is part of the filename, you don't need to use the ">" syntax in the [filemask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask), which would be for the file modified time.

Powershell will expand variables inside double-quoted strings ([Variable expansion in strings and here-strings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-here-strings/)), so you can use

```
$transferOptions.FileMask = "ABC*$dt*.zip"
```