# how to delete files on ftp server older then 10 days

Tags: date, command-line, server, ftp

I try to delete files on ftp server older than 10 days. How can I do this using command line? I guess that I need loops and functions of getting date from file.

Comment: What command-line? What is your local OS?

Comment: my local os is windows

Comment: And what "commandline" do you want to use? Batch file? PowerShell?

Comment: I want to use batch file

Comment: See [Delete files older than X days from FTP server with PowerShell or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38616995/850848).

Comment: I am trying to get winSCP on my computer and I hope your previous script will be useful for me!

Comment: Can you put back your removed answer?

Comment: I've removed it because I've realized that your question is exact duplicate of the question I've linked above. And my answer to that question contains everything already (including the batch file - it's at the very end).

Comment: okay I understood