# Is it possible to recursively delete files with more than X days in WinSCP batch file?

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

I have a script to transfer files from one server to other one.
With this I need to have a part of script to delete files with more than X days on the destination folder.

I check the WinSCP documentation, forum and all other information and I didn't find out anything, anyone can help me.

I've tried loops to get inside folders and delete each file with more than X days, nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible with simple WinSCP scripting.

But it is easy with [WinSCP .NET assembly and e.g. a PowerShell script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell).

At the end of my answer to this question, you will find a full code for non-recursive delete:
[Delete files older than X days from FTP server with PowerShell or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38616995/850848)

To find old files recursively, modify it with use of [`Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles) like this:

```bash
$oldFiles  =
    $session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(
        "/remote/path", $Null, [WinSCP.EnumerationOptions]::AllDirectories) |
    Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory } | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit }
```