# Read folder paths from FTP directory to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I'm currently working on a .NET 4.6 console application. I need to parse a couple of XML files from different directories on my FTP server. I thought the best approach would be, to read all file paths and store them into an `IEnumerable`, to process them further (Serialize XML Files to objects).

The root FTP path looks like this:

```
string urlFtpServer = @"ftp://128.0.1.70";
```

File paths look like this:

```
string file1 = @"ftp://128.0.1.70/MyFolder1/Mainfile.xml";
string file2 = @"ftp://128.0.1.70/MyFolder1/Subfile.xml";
string file3 = @"ftp://128.0.1.70/MyFolder2/Mainfile.xml";
string file4 = @"ftp://128.0.1.70/MyFolder2/Subfile.xml";
string file5 = @"ftp://128.0.1.70/MyFolder3/Mainfile.xml";
```

My question is, do you know how I can get those specific file paths?

I currently can read the folders of my FTP directory with this coding:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string url = @"ftp://128.0.1.70";

    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("My-User", "mypassword");

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

    Console.WriteLine("Directory List Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

    reader.Close();
    response.Close();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Do you know how I can read all file paths from the FTP main directory and possibly store them into a `List<string>`?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: None of those paths are the main directory they are in MyFolder1, 2 and 3.. you can itterate through all the paths looking for files that match Mainfile.xml and subfile.xml ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using FtpWebRequest

The `FtpWebRequest` does not have any explicit support for recursive file operations (including listing). You have to implement the recursion yourself:

- List the remote directory
- Iterate the entries, recursing into subdirectories (listing them again, etc.)

Tricky part is to identify files from subdirectories. There's no way to do that in a portable way with the `FtpWebRequest`. The `FtpWebRequest` unfortunately does not support the `MLSD` command, which is the only portable way to retrieve directory listing with file attributes in FTP protocol. See also [Checking if object on FTP server is file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36895021/850848).

Your options are:

- Do an operation on a file name that is certain to fail for file and succeeds for directories (or vice versa). I.e. you can try to download the "name". If that succeeds, it's a file, if that fails, it's a directory.
- You may be lucky and in your specific case, you can tell a file from a directory by a file name (i.e. all your files have an extension, while subdirectories do not)
- You use a long directory listing (`LIST` command = `ListDirectoryDetails` method) and try to parse a server-specific listing. Many FTP servers use *nix-style listing, where you identify a directory by the `d` at the very beginning of the entry. But many servers use a different format. The following example uses this approach (assuming the *nix format)

```
void ListFtpDirectory(
    string url, string rootPath, NetworkCredential credentials, List<string> list)
{
    FtpWebRequest listRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + rootPath);
    listRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
    listRequest.Credentials = credentials;

    List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    using (FtpWebResponse listResponse = (FtpWebResponse)listRequest.GetResponse())
    using (Stream listStream = listResponse.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader listReader = new StreamReader(listStream))
    {
        while (!listReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            lines.Add(listReader.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string[] tokens =
            line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 9, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string name = tokens[8];
        string permissions = tokens[0];

        string filePath = rootPath + name;

        if (permissions[0] == 'd')
        {
            ListFtpDirectory(url, filePath + "/", credentials, list);
        }
        else
        {
            list.Add(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Use the function like:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "mypassword");
string url = "ftp://ftp.example.com/";
ListFtpDirectory(url, "", credentials, list);
```

---

### Using 3rd party library

If you want to avoid troubles with parsing the server-specific directory listing formats, use a 3rd party library that supports the `MLSD` command and/or parsing various `LIST` listing formats; and recursive downloads.

For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) you can list whole directory with a single call to the [`Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles):

```
// Setup session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "ftp.example.com",
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "mypassword",
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // List files
    IEnumerable<string> list =
        session.EnumerateRemoteFiles("/", null, EnumerationOptions.AllDirectories).
        Select(fileInfo => fileInfo.FullName);
}
```

Internally, WinSCP uses the `MLSD` command, if supported by the server. If not, it uses the `LIST` command and supports dozens of different listing formats.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Thanks for that honorable response, great help! :)