# PowerShell How can I delete a directory with FTP?

Tags: .net, powershell, ftp, ftpwebrequest

From the [this list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp_fields(v=vs.110).aspx) of Web Request Method Fields, I've successfully deleted files from my server via FTP, by basically filling in the guide on [this page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2e07df8a-c7cd-47be-8e13-35de9b9189a8/remove-files-on-ftp-site-with-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell) with minor alterations:

```
$url = "ftp://server.net/path/to/place/FILE.txt"
$userName = "username"
$password = "p@ssw0rd!"

$ftpreq = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::create($url)
$ftpreq.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($userName, $password)
$ftpreq.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::DeleteFile

$ftpreq.GetResponse()
```

The file is named `FILE.txt`, the folder is named `FOLDER`.

When I try to do something similar, but for a folder, I get PowerShell errors and 550 response.

I've tried basically two variations on the file deletion method.

#### Try 1: Change URL to match folder name, keep method

Note that the folder I'm attempting to delete is next to the file I have already successfully deleted.

```
$url = "ftp://server.net/path/to/place/FOLDER"
$userName = "username"
$password = "p@ssw0rd!"

$ftpreq = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::create($url)
$ftpreq.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($userName, $password)
$ftpreq.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::DeleteFile

$ftpreq.GetResponse()
```

> Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable
>   (e.g., file not found, no access).

#### Try 2: Change method

```
$url = "ftp://server.net/path/to/place/FOLDER"
$userName = "username"
$password = "p@ssw0rd!"

$ftpreq = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::create($url)
$ftpreq.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($userName, $password)
$ftpreq.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::RemoveDirectory

$ftpreq.GetResponse()
```

> Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable
>   (e.g., file not found, no access)."

---

## Solution Implemented

```
function DeleteFtpFolder($url, $credentials)
{
    $listRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $listRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectoryDetails
    $listRequest.Credentials = $credentials

    $lines = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    $listResponse = $listRequest.GetResponse()
    $listStream = $listResponse.GetResponseStream()
    $listReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($listStream)

    while (!$listReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        $line = $listReader.ReadLine()
        $lines.Add($line) | Out-Null
    }

    $listReader.Dispose()
    $listStream.Dispose()
    $listResponse.Dispose()

    foreach ($line in $lines)
    {
        $tokens = $line.Split(" ", 5, [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

        $type = $tokens[2]
        $name = $tokens[3]
        $fileUrl = ($url + "/" + $name)

        if ($type -eq "<DIR>")
        {
            Write-Host "Found folder: $name"

            DeleteFtpFolder $fileUrl $credentials

            Write-Host "Deleting folder: $name"
            $deleteRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($fileUrl)
            $deleteRequest.Credentials = $credentials
            $deleteRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::RemoveDirectory
            $deleteRequest.GetResponse() | Out-Null
        }
        else 
        {
            $fileUrl = ($url + "/" + $name)
            Write-Host "Deleting file: $name"

            $deleteRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($fileUrl)
            $deleteRequest.Credentials = $credentials
            $deleteRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::DeleteFile
            $deleteRequest.GetResponse() | Out-Null
        }
    }
}

$credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($AzureFtpUsername, $AzureFtpPassword)
$url = $AzureFtpUrl

DeleteFtpFolder $url $credentials
```

The setup is an embedded PowerShell script inside a process step inside Octopus Deploy.  That's why I call the function at the bottom.

This solution is nearly identical to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50148863/726336), with some minor alterations on where I put the recursive call and how the returned data from the server gets parsed.  His solution seems like it looks more like an `ls` output, with more columns, whereas mine looked somewhat more like a `dir` output, with fewer columns.  But even then, it didn't look like the `dir` output on my local windows machine, so I'm not really sure exactly what is going on.  But it works, so that's good enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RMD` FTP command (`RemoveDirectory` method) fails, if the directory is not empty.

Typically it fails with an error like:

> 550 Directory not empty.

Unfortunately `FtpWebRequest` has a bad habit of "translating" the FTP error codes to its own messages. In this case, it "translates" 550 to:

> File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

What hides the real problem.

---

Anyway, there's no support for recursive operations in the [`FtpWebRequest` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest) (or any other FTP implementation in the .NET framework). You have to implement the recursion yourself:

- List the remote directory
- Iterate the entries, deleting files and recursing into subdirectories (listing them again, etc.)

Tricky part is to identify files from subdirectories. There's no way to do that in a portable way with the `FtpWebRequest`. The `FtpWebRequest` unfortunately does not support the `MLSD` command, which is the only portable way to retrieve directory listing with file attributes in FTP protocol. See also [Checking if object on FTP server is file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36895021/850848).

Your options are:

- Do an operation on a file name that is certain to fail for a file and to succeed for directory (or vice versa). I.e. you can try to download the "name". If that succeeds, it's a file, if that fails, it's a directory. But that can become a performance problem, when you have a large number of entries.
- You may be lucky and in your specific case, you can tell a file from a directory by a file name (i.e. all your files have an extension, while subdirectories do not)
- You use a long directory listing (`LIST` command = `ListDirectoryDetails` method) and try to parse a server-specific listing. Many FTP servers use *nix-style listing, where you identify a directory by the `d` at the very beginning of the entry. But many servers use a different format. The following example uses this approach (assuming the *nix format).
- In this specific case, you can just try to delete the entry as a file. If deleting fails, try to list the entry as a directory. If the listing succeeds, you assume it's a folder and proceed accordingly. Unfortunately some servers do not error, when you try to list a file. They will just return a listing with a single entry for the file.

```
function DeleteFtpFolder($url, $credentials)
{
    $listRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $listRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::ListDirectoryDetails
    $listRequest.Credentials = $credentials

    $lines = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    $listResponse = $listRequest.GetResponse()
    $listStream = $listResponse.GetResponseStream()
    $listReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($listStream)
    while (!$listReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        $line = $listReader.ReadLine()
        $lines.Add($line) | Out-Null
    }
    $listReader.Dispose()
    $listStream.Dispose()
    $listResponse.Dispose()

    foreach ($line in $lines)
    {
        $tokens = $line.Split(" ", 9, [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
        $name = $tokens[8]
        $permissions = $tokens[0]

        $fileUrl = ($url + $name)

        if ($permissions[0] -eq 'd')
        {
            DeleteFtpFolder ($fileUrl + "/") $credentials
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "Deleting file $name"
            $deleteRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($fileUrl)
            $deleteRequest.Credentials = $credentials
            $deleteRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::DeleteFile
            $deleteRequest.GetResponse() | Out-Null
        }
    }

    Write-Host "Deleting folder"
    $deleteRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $deleteRequest.Credentials = $credentials
    $deleteRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::RemoveDirectory
    $deleteRequest.GetResponse() | Out-Null
}
```

Use the function like:

```
$url = "ftp://ftp.example.com/path/to/folder/";
$credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
DeleteFtpFolder $url $credentials
```

---

Or use a 3rd party library that supports recursive operations.

For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) you can delete whole directory with a single call to [`Session.RemoveFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_removefiles):

```
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
    HostName = "ftp.example.com"
    UserName = "username"
    Password = "password"
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

# Connect
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

# Remove folder
$session.RemoveFiles("/path/to/folder").Check()

# Disconnect, clean up
$session.Dispose()
```

Internally, WinSCP uses the `MLSD` command, if supported by the server. If not, it uses the `LIST` command and supports dozens of different listing formats.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I was able to use the recursion solution you posted with some minor alterations to solve the problem.  The output I was getting back from the server looked more like `dir` than `ls`, so I wrote the code to look for the string `<DIR>` to distinguish file from folder.

Comment: Code to parse DOS listing (probably of IIS server) can be found at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7060983/850848#39771146 (it's in C# though, but it should not be difficult to translate to PowerShell). Though you cal also configure IIS to use *nix/`ls` style listing.

Answer (score 0):

Few changes in Martin Prikryl answer For Azure FTP
this will work on following format

```
"01-12-22  07:38AM       <DIR>          assets"
"12-16-21  12:22PM                  959 African Union.png"





 function DeleteFtpFolder( $url, $credentials)
{
    $listRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $listRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::ListDirectoryDetails
    $listRequest.Credentials = $credentials

    $lines = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    $listResponse = $listRequest.GetResponse()
    $listStream = $listResponse.GetResponseStream()
    $listReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($listStream)
    while (!$listReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        $line = $listReader.ReadLine()
        $lines.Add($line) | Out-Null
    }
    $listReader.Dispose()
    $listStream.Dispose()
    $listResponse.Dispose()

    foreach ($line in $lines)
    {
        $tokens = $line.split(" ", 4, StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
        $name = $tokens[3]
        $permissions = $tokens[2]

        $fileUrl = ($url + $name)

        if ($permissions[0] -eq '<dir>')
        {
            DeleteFtpFolder ($fileUrl + "/") $credentials
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "Deleting file $name"
            $deleteRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($fileUrl)
            $deleteRequest.Credentials = $credentials
            $deleteRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::DeleteFile
            $deleteRequest.GetResponse() | Out-Null
        }
    }

    Write-Host "Deleting folder"
    $deleteRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $deleteRequest.Credentials = $credentials
    $deleteRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::RemoveDirectory
    $deleteRequest.GetResponse() | Out-Null
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have SSH, use `lftp`:

```
 lftp  -e "set ftp:ssl-allow off;  rm -r  public_html/folder"  -d -u username,password  ftp://someftpserver.com/public_html/
```

It will delete all files and subdirs in the directory called `folder` recursively and display all actions in terminal by using the `-d` option.

However, it's insecure and Martin Prikryl is GOD, so maybe get SSH working.